# I want to draw double headed arrow between the two outer boxes. Can any one help?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\TBox[3][]{%
  \tikz\node[draw,ultra thick,text width=#2,align=center,#1] {#3};}

\begin{document}
\TBox{6cm}{%
  \TBox[fill=blue!30]{5cm}{A} \\
  \TBox[fill=cyan!30]{2.5cm}{A1}\quad\TBox[fill=magenta!30]{2.5cm}{A2}}
  \space{} \space{} 
\TBox{6cm}{%
  \TBox[fill=red!30]{5cm}{B} \\
  \TBox[fill=green!30]{2.5cm}{B1}\quad\TBox[fill=yellow!30]{2.5cm}{B2}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand\TBox[3][]{%
  \tikz\node[draw,ultra thick,text width=#2,align=center,#1] {#3};}

\begin{document}
\TBox{6cm}{%
  \TBox[fill=blue!30]{5cm}{A} \\
  \TBox[fill=cyan!30]{2.5cm}{A1}\quad\TBox[fill=magenta!30]{2.5cm}{A2}}
  \tikz[baseline=-7mm]\draw[->>,thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);  % <-----
\TBox{6cm}{%
  \TBox[fill=red!30]{5cm}{B} \\
  \TBox[fill=green!30]{2.5cm}{B1}\quad\TBox[fill=yellow!30]{2.5cm}{B2}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes. Thank You . It is working.

Comment: If answer solve your problem, than you may consider to up-vote it or even accept it by clicking on up-triangle and check mark respectively at top left side of answer ;-).